# TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable for Chinese program

Tags: python

So I'm trying to make a program for my Chinese class that gives me random characters to make a sentence with, but I keep getting the same error no matter what I try. Can someone tell me what is wrong with my code and how to fix it? Thank you!

```
#Chinese vocab character generator project
import random

characters = ['谁', '什么', '工作', '名字', '星期', '工程师', '做', '你', '您', '好', '多', '大', '姓', '学', '出生', '书', '年', '年纪', '妈妈', '爸爸', '上', '下', '我', '是', '太', '院', '电脑', '电话', '号', '吗', '吧', '春节', '在', '那', '哪', '哪儿', '爷爷', '老', '的', '号码', '手机', '公司', '就', '巧', '属', '先生', '中', '今', '天', '人', '岁', '一生']
numbers = ['零', '一', '二', '三', '四', '五', '六', '七', '八', '九', '十', '百', '千', '万']
particles = ['了', '的', '吧', '吗', '呢', '什么']

print("Welcome to the Random Character Generator!")
nr_characters= int(input("How many characters would you like?\n")) 
nr_numbers = int(input(f"How many numbers would you like?\n"))
nr_particles = int(input(f"How many particles would you like?\n"))

character_list = ("")
for characters in range(0, nr_characters + 1):
  character_list += characters[random.randint(0,30)]
for particle in range(0, 7 + 1):
  character_list += particles[random.randint(0,5)]
for number in range(0, nr_numbers + 1):
  character_list += str(numbers[random.randint(0,13)])

print("Your characters are: " + character_list)
```

Comment: The stacktrace tells you where the bug is: `characters[random.randint(0,30)]`

Comment: This is unrelated to your issue, but your `character_list` variable isn't actually containing a list (or even a tuple, despite some parentheses around its initial value). Misleading variable names like that can make it *very* hard to reason about this code if you need to come back to it after not having been working on it for a while.

Answer (score 2):

You're overwriting the `characters` variable defined at the top with the `for characters in ...` loop. Rename the variable in the first for loop:

```
#Chinese vocab character generator project
import random

characters = ['谁', '什么', '工作', '名字', '星期', '工程师', '做', '你', '您', '好', '多', '大', '姓', '学', '出生', '书', '年', '年纪', '妈妈', '爸爸', '上', '下', '我', '是', '太', '院', '电脑', '电话', '号', '吗', '吧', '春节', '在', '那', '哪', '哪儿', '爷爷', '老', '的', '号码', '手机', '公司', '就', '巧', '属', '先生', '中', '今', '天', '人', '岁', '一生']
numbers = ['零', '一', '二', '三', '四', '五', '六', '七', '八', '九', '十', '百', '千', '万']
particles = ['了', '的', '吧', '吗', '呢', '什么']

print("Welcome to the Random Character Generator!")
nr_characters= int(input("How many characters would you like?\n")) 
nr_numbers = int(input(f"How many numbers would you like?\n"))
nr_particles = int(input(f"How many particles would you like?\n"))

character_list = ("")
for character in range(0, nr_characters + 1):
  character_list += characters[random.randint(0,30)]
for particle in range(0, 7 + 1):
  character_list += particles[random.randint(0,5)]
for number in range(0, nr_numbers + 1):
  character_list += str(numbers[random.randint(0,13)])

print("Your characters are: " + character_list)
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe there is an error in this line:

```
character_list += characters[random.randint(0,30)]
```

The problem is you want to access the `characters` *list*, but you have also defined the same variable name for the loop. This is causing variable *overwriting* (mentioned by @sumit). Just change the variable name in the loop like this:

```
for character in range(0, nr_characters + 1):
```

Comment: Thank you so much! That fixed it. It's been a while since I last did some programming so I made a really silly mistake lol.